# Backoffice : Configure simple search widget to fetch records excluding subtype

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Hi I have created one custom item type and created another sub type as well which extends custom one.

In Backoffice, I have added configuration for simple-search, but by default, widget gives result including subtype as well.

I want simple-search to fetch only parent records (excluding subtype) when hitting search button. The idea is user can by-default search only parent records and if he wants he can check "include subtype" option in advanced-search.

I have made changes in advanced-search to not include sub-type but not able to understand how to do it in simple-search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In advanced-search you have the possibility to use `field-list` with the properties `disable-subtypes-checkbox` and  `includeSubtypes`. I don't think you need more customization (I don't know if that the change your talking about in your question). Cf. [Advanced Search Widget](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b50ccf3866910149e1c9ebdd47f12be.html)

In [Simple Search Widget](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c5ea26086691014807aa9cb939771b7.html), you do not have `field-list` hence you can't set the property you need.

You should use the advanced search widget that's all.

What's more, simple search is deprecated :

> Note that with 6.1.0.0 version of SAP Hybris Commerce, the Simple Search widget has been deprecated. It will be removed in the future releases. In the default Backoffice Administration Cockpit, the Advanced Search widget is used.

Comment: Yes, I used includeSubtypes="false" to uncheck "include subtype" option.

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt, you mean in simple search? Because this option is only available using advanced search.

Comment: no not in simple search, i used it in advanced search only since we don't have field-list in simple search. You are right, I need to only have advanced search that's all. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @alain.janinm, I just remove simple search widget from my config file and now i have only advanced search widget for my custom type, still i am seeing simple search widget. Is there any way i can completely replace simple search with advanced search all over the places for my custom type ?

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt Have you set the `disableSimpleSearch` setting to true? (`<setting key="disableSimpleSearch" type="Boolean">true</setting>`)

Comment: did ShreshttBhatt become an FOSS Brain ?